# How If-then-else works in SAS

Tags: sas

While learning sas tutorial from PSU. `https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat480/lesson/welcome-stat-480`.

I Came across these sentences:

Note that, in general, using ELSE statements with IF-THEN statements can save resources:

Using IF-THEN statements without the ELSE statement causes SAS to evaluate all IF-THEN statements.
Using IF-THEN statements with the ELSE statement causes SAS to execute IF-THEN statements until it encounters the first true statement. Subsequent IF-THEN statements are not evaluated.

can someone explain me the above lesson with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a series of mutually exclusive logical evaluations placed in consecutive `IF/THEN` statements.

```
length word $10;
word='Infinity';
if x=1 then word='One;
if x=2 then word='Two';
if x=3 then word='Three';
if x=4 then word='Four';
if x=5 then word='Five';
```

Only one evaluation is true, but all five need to be evaluated.  By linking the separate statements with `ELSE` you are creating one large statement that will complete as soon
a single `IF` test evaluates to true.

Here I put the `ELSE` at the start of the line for emphasis.

```
     if x=1 then word='One;
else if x=2 then word='Two';
else if x=3 then word='Three';
else if x=4 then word='Four';
else if x=5 then word='Five';
else word='Infinity';
```

Consider the situation when `x` is `3`, the tests `x=4` and `x=5` do **not** need to be performed.  That is your resource saving.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in the first version of my code to translate fruit colors, the computer will for a yellow fruit first test if it is red, then if it is yellow, then if it is green and then if it is blue

```
data DUTCH_FRUIT;
   set ENGLISH_FRUIT;
   if color eq 'red' 
      then kleur = 'rood';
   if color eq 'yellow' 
      then kleur = 'geel';
   if color eq 'green' 
      then kleur = 'groen';
   if color eq 'blue' 
      then kleur = 'blauw';
run;
```

While in the second, it will only test if it is red and then yellow, but never if it is green or blue, which is more efficient

```
data DUTCH_FRUIT;
   set ENGLISH_FRUIT;
   if color eq 'red' 
      then kleur = 'rood';
      else if color eq 'yellow' 
         then kleur = 'geel';
         else if color eq 'green' 
            then kleur = 'groen';
            else if color eq 'blue' 
               then kleur = 'blauw';
run;
```